# how to make an array into array of arrays in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, dictionary

I have a query `company_in_outs = company.in_outs.where('date >= ? and date <= ?', Date.today.at_beginning_of_month, Date.today.end_of_month)` which is returning me `<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation`. now i want to make this array into an array of arrays, those are grouped based on the date value.

```
for example.

#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<InOut id: 2806, date: "2016-06-01", created_at: "2016-06-02 07:01:52", updated_at: "2016-06-16 07:43:45", company_id: 1>,#<InOut id: 2806, date: "2016-06-01", created_at: "2016-06-02 07:01:52", updated_at: "2016-06-16 07:43:45", company_id: 1>,#<InOut id: 2806, date: "2016-06-01", created_at: "2016-06-02 07:01:52", updated_at: "2016-06-16 07:43:45", company_id: 1>,#<InOut id: 2806, date: "2016-06-02", created_at: "2016-06-02 07:01:52", updated_at: "2016-06-16 07:43:45", company_id: 1>,#<InOut id: 2806, date: "2016-06-02", created_at: "2016-06-02 07:01:52", updated_at: "2016-06-16 07:43:45", company_id: 1>,#<InOut id: 2806, check_in: "2016-06-24 16:16:00", check_out: "2016-06-25 01:16:00", date: "2016-06-01", created_at: "2016-06-02 07:01:52", updated_at: "2016-06-16 07:43:45", company_id: 1> ]
```

from this array i want to make an `array of arrays`, which needs to be `grouped` based on the `date`. meaning all records which contains `same date` needs to be `grouped` as `one array`. like this i want to have an `array of arrays`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have all the records loaded:

```
company_in_outs.each_with_object({}) do |record, hash|
  (hash[record.date] ||= []) << record
end.values
```

if you aren't using Rails (ActiveSupport) you should use inject instead of each_with_object

```
company_in_outs.inject({}) do |hash, record|
  (hash[record.date] ||= []) << record
  hash
end.values
```

I think you should be able to done sorting on db site too.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a `group_by` method in Array, but instead of returning array of array, it returns an object with key and array of the same key as value.

In your case:

```
company_in_outs.group_by do |com|
    com.date
end
```

The code above will return an object grouped by date as a key, and array of the same date as value.

You could loop through the returning object which will return key and value, and do whatever you like :)

Hope this helps!